# Silverlight 3 - No Built In Menu Control?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

Is there no such thing as built in menu control in Silverlight 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.

Try:

http://slmenu.codeplex.com/

http://sl4popupmenu.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly not http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/126386/284027.aspx